# Table and MatSort not working with observables

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-observables

I've been trying to follow the guide for sortable tables in Materials (https://material.angular.io/components/sort/overview), and using it with a custom array instead of their sample database isn't quite working for me when I try to create the Observable with the merge function in the example (it works when I create it with Observable.of() )

My datasource looks like:

```
export class StallEventsDataSource extends DataSource<StallEvent> {
  constructor(private stallEvents: StallEvent[], private _sort: MatSort) {
    super();
  }

  connect(): Observable<StallEvent[]> {
    const displayDataChanges = [
      this._sort.sortChange
    ];

    return Observable.merge(...displayDataChanges).map(() => {
      return this.getSortedData();
    });
  }

  disconnect() {
  }

  getSortedData(): StallEvent[] {
    return this.stallEvents;
  }
}
```

The data shows up (without the sorting functionality, unsurprisingly), if I change

```
return Observable.merge(...displayDataChanges).map(() => {
  return this.getSortedData();
});
```

to

```
return Observable.of(this.getSortedData());
```

If it helps, here is the template:

```
 <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>

   <ng-container matColumnDef="VideoTime">
     <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Video Time </mat-header-cell>
     <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.VideoTime}} </mat-cell>
   </ng-container>

   <ng-container matColumnDef="Duration">
     <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Duration </mat-header-cell>
     <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.Duration}} </mat-cell>
   </ng-container>

   <ng-container matColumnDef="AbsoluteStartTime">
     <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Absolute Start Time </mat-header-cell>
     <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{getDateString(row.TimestampStart)}} </mat-cell>
   </ng-container>

   <ng-container matColumnDef="AbsoluteEndTime">
     <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Absolute End Time </mat-header-cell>
     <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{getDateString(row.TimestampEnd)}} </mat-cell>
   </ng-container>

   <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="['VideoTime', 'Duration', 'AbsoluteStartTime','AbsoluteEndTime']"></mat-header-row>
   <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: ['VideoTime', 'Duration', 'AbsoluteStartTime','AbsoluteEndTime']"></mat-row>

 </mat-table>
```

Does anyone have any insight into what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Just try this, change

```
return Observable.merge(...displayDataChanges).map(() => {
```

to

```
return Observable.merge(this.sort.sortChange).map(() => {
```